# php mail not working in rhel server?

Tags: email, php, tcp, smtp

I have installed roundcube mail and when it tried to use installer which uses php mail it is loading for 5 to 10 minutes and then telling me 'ok' but no mail comes to me. smtp_port is 25 host is localhost in my php.ini file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is configure set `sendmail -t` under unix line to `/usr/sbin/sendmail -t` and then configure `postfix`